# ERROR: unsupported or misplaced expression using

Tags: syntax, package, julia, using

I'm working on a mac (OS X El Capitan), and I have an unregistered julia package called `ME-Private.jl` (that's how it's labeled on github) that I want to debug in the Julia REPL. I cloned this package into `/Users/myname/.julia/v0.4`, where the rest of my packages reside. All my packages work and I have a mix of registered and unregistered packages. Now, when I typed

```
Pkg.clone("url", "ME-Private")
```

in the Julia REPL, it cloned just like I wanted into the `v0.4` directory. However, when I start up Julia again, I type

```
using ME-Private
```

and it passes me the following error.

```
ERROR: unsupported or misplaced expression using
```

My hypothesis is that there is a problem with having a `-` in the title of a package, but that's how the repository is named (of which I'm not author), and I'm aware that ideally the packages are named identically to the repos which they are local versions of.

That being said, I have tried renaming the package MEPrivate to avoid the `-` issue and `MEPrivate` still shows up in the list of packages returned by `Pkg.status()`, but when I type

```
using MEPrivate
```

it passes the following error

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: MEPrivate not found in path
 in require at /Applications/Julia-0.4.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
```

even though `Pkg.status()` returns a list of packages including `MEPrivate`!

My two questions are:

1. Is it bad practice to have a `-` in the title of an online or local repo of this nature (or a `.jl`, while we're on the subject of titles)?
2. How do I fix this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the package publicly available on GitHub?  If so, perhaps include a link to it?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not @MichaelOhlrogge

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is bad to have `-` in the title of a package!

Try

```
@eval using $(Symbol("ME-Private"))
```

but get the package author to fix the problem.